# Rock, Paper, Scissors Python 2 Game Statistics

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner with Python attempting to create a RPS game with Python 2. I believe that I have the basic game  and rules coded myself, however as I have browsed around different RPS python code posts I have confused myself and do not know how to continue using the def style I have already and fulfill my requirements.

I do not know how to keep track of how many "gestures" have occurred in each game (as I need to calculate the average number of gestures per game at the end).

I also need to implement coding that will allow me to keep track of and present the final stats for : Player/computer wins, percentage of  player/computer wins, and the average number of "gestures" (user inputs) per game to determine a winner.

Please be aware that I have put numerous hours into this myself (I am teaching myself) and that I am not simply seeking "easy answers" but that I am frustrated enough to seek help independently.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Here is my current code:

```
import random

def Welcome(Name):
    print "Welcome " + Name
    print "We're going to play rock, paper, scissors."

def ChoiceSelection(PlayerChoice,ComputerChoice):
    print "You chose: " + PlayerChoice
    print "The computer chose: " + ComputerChoice

def GameRules(PlayerChoice,ComputerChoice,Name):
    if PlayerChoice == ComputerChoice:
        print "Draw, nobody wins."

    if PlayerChoice == "Rock" and ComputerChoice == "Scissors":
        print Name + " wins!"
    elif PlayerChoice == "Paper" and ComputerChoice == "Rock":
        print Name + " wins!"
    elif PlayerChoice == "Scissors" and ComputerChoice == "Paper":
        print Name + " wins!"

    if ComputerChoice == "Rock" and PlayerChoice == "Scissors":
        print "The computer wins!"
    elif ComputerChoice == "Paper" and PlayerChoice == "Rock":
        print "The computer wins!"
    elif ComputerChoice == "Scissors" and PlayerChoice == "Paper":
        print "The computer wins!"


def main():

    while True:

        Name = raw_input("Player Name: ")

        Welcome(Name)

        print "Please make your selection: Rock, Paper, or Scissors"
        print "Remember, your choices are case sensitive!"

        PlayerChoice = raw_input("Your selection: ")
        ComputerChoice = random.choice(["Rock","Paper","Scissors"])

        ChoiceSelection(PlayerChoice,ComputerChoice)
        GameRules(PlayerChoice,ComputerChoice,Name)

main()
```

Comment: It's unclear to me where you're stuck though. What have you _tried_ to do to keep track of gestures, and to count wins-losses? What isn't working as you would expect? I'm sure someone could re-write your entire program, tell you how to better modularize your `GameRules` function, and nicely track everything you need tracked, but that might not be so helpful for whatever you aren't understanding.

Comment: I just don't understand how to do those things. I've seen some vague ways of doing it but I just don't understand how to do those things due to my limited knowledge of Python2.7.

Comment: If you want to have an easier time with the game logic, I suggest, that instead of keeping track of RPS as stings, try using 0,1,2 for each choice, and see how you can implement the function, then.
Also, if you want a direction to develop, try coding Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need at least one, or perhaps more, data structures / variables to hold that data. Considering how your code is structured, it seems like they could easily be created on main() and kept there (that is, you won't even need to pass em to other functions). What data structures (if any) to use to hold that data, i'll leave it to you.
2. Since now there's *something* that needs to remember the win/lose/draw ratio on main(), it seems like you need some way for main to actually find out what happened in a round, so that it can be saved on said *something* for later. As things are now, main only asks another function to *print* what happened, not to *tell them* what happened, so you may need to change some things in your auxiliar functions.
3. Particularily, you may want a function with similar checks to `GameRules` that can `return ROUND_RESULT` with `ROUND_RESULT` being anything you may want to use to represent if there was a "win", a "lose" or a "draw". And once you have that, `GameRules` becomes a little redundant so you may want to clean it up a bit by calling this new function instead.